# Does the movie "In Time" have a previous film?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I recall watching this movie in 1999, but it looks like it was filmed on the late 70s. Basically it has the same plot as the one with Justin Timberlake, the humans born and a lifespan-counter device is implanted to them. They use the "timespan" as currency for everything. The difference with the modern one is that the device is a small white box, similar to the glucose test machine and it has a cable attached to the arm. I'm pretty sure I didn't dreamed it because I was watching this with my dad, I even told about it too some of my friends but it looks like only my dad and I watched it, and I've just discovered the one with Justin Timberlake and it was a shock! I've tried googling the "In time" based on history but I had no results, only a sueing threatening but nothing else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Could it be you saw (and are not recalling exactly) the short (40 min) movie [*The Price of Life*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0366919/) from 1987?

Time is used as currency just as in *In Time*, but people carry around little point-of-sale like terminals (which are white) to make transactions.  Personal time, however, is stored on black swipe cards.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Price_of_Life_(1987_film)) for the movie describes it as an unacknowledged precursor to *In Time*.

Comment: Yes, this was the one I was looking for. I could swear the it was older than that. Thank you!